# Scala - Handle empty strings when instantiating a class

Tags: scala

I have a case class with a couple of String fields. I use the values result of a string split to instantiate the class, but want to get an error when any of the fields is an empty string. For example:

```
case class SomeClass(a: String, b: String)
val line = ",a"
val values = line.split(",")
SomeClass(values(0), values(1))
```

Would result in:

```
SomeClass = SomeClass(,a)
```

Obviously I can check if each element is empty individually, but is there any more elegant and practical way to prevent instantiating when there is an empty field?

Comment: What's the preferred prevention? Fails to compile? Throws runtime exception? Returns `Option[SomeClass]`? Returns `null`?

Comment: @jwvh Returning Option[SomeClass], with None if any of the values is empty would be ideal

Comment: Thinking a little bit outside the box, why not just use a refined type ```NonEmptyString``` It seems very non-intuitive to me, to delegate this functionality to the constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer **requires** external libraries and may not work for you if you want to stick to core Scala but I am going to encourage this mainly because, a constructor is a contract. Here it says `You give me 2 strings and I will give you SomeClass` i.e. `::String -> String -> SomeClass`. The fact that this may not be honored even when the input meets the criteria breaks the soundness in my opinion. There are a few things, I would suggest

**1) Use Refined Types**

```
import eu.timepit.refined.types.string._
import eu.timepit.refined._
import eu.timepit.refined.auto._

case class SomeClass(a: NonEmptyString, b: NonEmptyString)
```

Would make it impossible to construct this with an empty string. You can do whatever you want with the error.

2) If you don't want to use refined types => I think `Either` gives you more power, as to why things failed. A good option would be `Validated` semigroup.

```
import cats.data._
import cats.data.Validated._
import cats.implicits._

sealed trait ValidationError {
  def error: String
}

case object StringIsEmptyError extends ValidationError{
  def error = "Argument Can't Be Empty String"
}

type ValidationResult[A] = ValidatedNec[ValidationError, A]

def validateArgument(s: String): ValidationResult[String] = if (s.nonEmpty) s.validNec else StringIsEmptyError.invalidNec

object SomeClass {
  def apply(a: String, b: String) = (validateArgument(a), validateArgument(b)).mapN(SomeClass).toEither
}
```

This is a little bit more code than you might want but I think it is easier to reason about + easily extensible should you have more requirements about the arguments in the future.

One good thing about Validated, as opposed to `Option` or `Either` is that, it allows you to accumulate errors. So in this case, if both arguments were empty, you could collect both errors and report to the user, rather than ambiguously failing

Comment: I wanted to avoid using extra libraries, however this answer is very educative.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try.

In the companion object create one or more factory methods that construct and validate the expected parameters. Make the primary constructor private so that the factory method/s can't be circumnavigated.

```
case class SomeClass private (a: String, b: String)
object SomeClass {

  def apply(ab: String): Option[SomeClass] = util.Try{
    val Array(a, b) = ab.split(",")
    apply(a, b)
  }.getOrElse(None)

  def apply(a: String, b: String): Option[SomeClass] =
    if (a.isEmpty || b.isEmpty) None
    else Some(new SomeClass(a, b))
}
```

testing:

```
SomeClass("aa,bb") //res0: Option[SomeClass] = Some(SomeClass(aa,bb))
SomeClass(",cc")   //res1: Option[SomeClass] = None
SomeClass("g:g")   //res2: Option[SomeClass] = None
new SomeClass("x", "y")  //fails to compile
```

Comment: I like this approach, since it does the splitting inside. However I get the following error when pasting it on the terminal. Maybe because I'm using an older version of scala.

Comment: @Jack, what error are you getting and what version are you running? This tests fine on Scala 2.12.7 and 2.13.1.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to paste it: error: constructor SomeClass in class SomeClass cannot be accessed in object SomeClass else Some(new SomeClass(a, b)). Im using 2.11.12

Comment: Mmm, 2.11.12 _is_ pretty old. I'm unable to reproduce the error. You might have to forgo the `private` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can define companion object with apply function.

```scala
case class SomeClass(a: String, b: String)

object SomeClass {
  def apply(a: String, b: String): SomeClass = {
     if (a.trim.isEmpty || b.trim.isEmpty) throw new IllegalArgumentException
     SomeClass(a, b)
  }
}
```

```
@ SomeClass("", "b")
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
  ammonite.$sess.cmd4$SomeClass$.apply(cmd4.sc:3)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd5$.<init>(cmd5.sc:1)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd5$.<clinit>(cmd5.sc)
```

Comment: This solution is very simple and I like it, however it raises an error when trying to compile the project. ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[error] both method apply in object SomeClass and  method apply in object SomeClass match argument types (String,String) and expected result type SomeClass.

Answer (score 1):

```
case class SomeClass(a: String, b: String) {
  require(a.nonEmpty && b.nonEmpty, "a and b cannot be empty")
}
```

You can achieve it with simple require. But if you want to stricten it based on the type at compile-time, you can use `NonEmptyString` as suggested in the above answers by @sinanspd.

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/shankarshastri/uPk8ZMqCQUa5G3RcKfZtwA/